# Python - Calculate time difference between rows regarding their labels from a txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sorting, datetime

[image]I am reading data from a txt file which has time stamps. I need to read data from a txt file and write the result in a different txt file. Therefore, I need to sort the data.

For example, I need to calculate time difference for XXXXXX between 2020-08-28T11:46:24.8419656Z and 2020-08-28T11:48:11.8418281Z, which is total time diff. To calculate "Execution" time, I need to subtract between 2020-08-28T11:48:11.8418281Z and 2020-08-28T11:46:39.9417366Z. These are just example to calculate time diff. If there is a error, I need to print in "Test Status" as 1. There is an error in YYYYYY so I just need to assign time status if they are not exist as 0. In output, I gave the values to show them as an example.

How can I calculate time diff because there is T in middle of time stamp? Also another challenge is that I need to calculate between two rows regarding their label in column. To find out the name of time stamps(e.g XXXXXXX), I need to check "#########" and then I can sort it otherwise I dont know which name is coming in txt file.

```
from datetime import datetime

def time_diff(start, end):
    start_dt = datetime.strptime(start, '%H:%M:%S')
    end_dt = datetime.strptime(end, '%H:%M:%S')
    diff = (end_dt - start_dt)
    return diff.seconds

scores = {}
with open('input.txt') as fin:
    for line in fin.readlines():
        values = line.split(',')
        scores[values[0]] = time_diff(values[0],values[0])

with open('result.txt', 'w') as fout:
    for key, value in sorted(scores.iteritems(), key=lambda (k,v): (v,k)):
        fout.write('%s,%s\n' % (key, value))

INPUT:

2020-08-28T11:46:24.8419656Z ################################################################################
2020-08-28T11:46:24.8419656Z XXXXXX
2020-08-28T11:46:39.9397372Z Execution 0
2020-08-28T11:46:39.9417366Z Creation 0
2020-08-28T11:46:41.4877509Z Build 0
2020-08-28T11:48:02.6957708Z Level 0 
2020-08-28T11:48:02.7227683Z Converting file start
2020-08-28T11:48:11.7408315Z Converting done 0
2020-08-28T11:48:11.8148285Z Checking results
2020-08-28T11:48:11.8418281Z Test Status XXXXXX: Success
2020-08-28T11:48:11.8498273Z ################################################################################
2020-08-28T11:48:11.8498273Z YYYYYY
2020-08-28T11:48:27.1533026Z Execution 0
2020-08-28T11:48:27.1583035Z Creation 0
2020-08-28T11:48:28.6763028Z Build 0
2020-08-28T11:49:31.9180832Z Level 0 
2020-08-28T11:49:31.9440848Z ##[error]
2020-08-28T11:49:31.9530839Z ################################################################################
2020-08-28T11:50:24.8419656Z ZZZZZZ
2020-08-28T11:50:39.9397372Z Execution 0
2020-08-28T11:50:39.9417366Z Creation 0
2020-08-28T11:50:41.4877509Z Build 0
2020-08-28T11:51:02.6957708Z Level 0 
2020-08-28T11:51:02.7227683Z Converting file start
2020-08-28T11:51:11.7408315Z Converting done 0
2020-08-28T11:51:11.8148285Z Checking results
2020-08-28T11:51:11.8418281Z Test Status ZZZZZZ: Success
2020-08-28T11:51:31.9530839Z ################################################################################



OUTPUT:

Name       Total    Execution Creation Build Level Converting  Checking results   Test Status      
XXXXXX      10          2        2       2     2        2          2       2          0
YYYYYY      10          2        2       2     2        0          0       0          1
ZZZZZZ      10          2        2       2     2        2          2       2          0
```

Comment: Hi, is the `INPUT` same as `input.txt` because I don't see any commas in `INPUT`. Please attach an image of the `input.txt' file.

Comment: The strings can be converted to `datetime` objects using `dateutil.parser.isoparse`. Here's the link on how to do this  (https://discuss.python.org/t/parse-z-timezone-suffix-in-datetime/2220).

Comment: @r0ot293 yes, it is same as input file.

Comment: May I ask how are you assigning values to Execution, Creation etc. in the output? Is it the time difference between two lines?

Comment: @r0ot293 thanks for helping, I am assigning the values for example for the "Execution" for XXXXXX, It is between from 2020-08-28T11:46:39.9397372Z to 2020-08-28T11:46:39.9417366Z. It means that when it pass the other one, "Execution" time is between "Execution and Creation". To calculate "Creation", start 2020-08-28T11:46:39.9417366Z and end 2020-08-28T11:46:41.4877509Z ( until Build).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
from dateutil import parser
import pandas as pd

with open('input.txt') as file:
    data = file.read()

timestamps = re.findall(r'(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}.+Z)\s#{3,}', data)
text = []
dict_list = []
for i in range(len(timestamps)-1):
    text.append(data[data.index(timestamps[i]):data.index(timestamps[i+1])])
    time_diff = parser.isoparse(timestamps[i+1]) - parser.isoparse(timestamps[i])
    # print(text[-1])
    lines = text[-1].split('\n')
    dict = {}
    dict['name'] = lines[1].split(' ')[1]
    dict['execution'] = (parser.isoparse(lines[3].split(' ')[0]) - parser.isoparse(lines[2].split(' ')[0])).seconds
    dict['creation'] = (parser.isoparse(lines[4].split(' ')[0]) - parser.isoparse(lines[3].split(' ')[0])).seconds
    dict['build'] = (parser.isoparse(lines[5].split(' ')[0]) - parser.isoparse(lines[4].split(' ')[0])).seconds
    dict['level'] = (parser.isoparse(lines[6].split(' ')[0]) - parser.isoparse(lines[5].split(' ')[0])).seconds
    if "error" in lines[-2]:
        dict['test_status'] = 1
        dict_list.append(dict)
        continue
    elif "Success" in lines[-2]:
        dict['test_status'] = 0
        dict['converting'] = (parser.isoparse(lines[7].split(' ')[0]) - parser.isoparse(lines[6].split(' ')[0])).seconds
        dict['checking'] = (parser.isoparse(lines[8].split(' ')[0]) - parser.isoparse(lines[7].split(' ')[0])).seconds
    dict_list.append(dict)


df = pd.DataFrame(dict_list)
df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

You can get all timestamps in this way and then you can get data between two timestamps by slicing data. Let me know if there's any issue.

Comment: But the goal is that I need to calculate time difference between two time stamps regarding their end of time. For example, I need to define what is the name of what I am doing. Therefore,first of all, I need to catch XXXXXX, YYYYYY, ZZZZZZ. Then I need to calculate time difference for total time, Execution, Build, Creation. First I need to check column 1 and #####, then catch name as XXXXXXX. After that start to calculate time diff

Comment: @nobody try and run the above code I've set `dict['name']` with respective values like 'XXXX..' or 'YYYY..'. and the `time_diff` variable stores the difference between two timestamps that are followed by #.

Comment: I am getting "NameError: name 'parser' is not defined"

Comment: @nobody I forgot to `import` parser, try the new code it should solve the entire thing. Let me know if it works or any error comes up.

Comment: thank you very much it is working, there is one more thing. If difference is less than 0.01 it calculates as 0 but it should write full digit number. Second, you checked according to line number as between lline[4]- line[3]. Maybe line numbers might be incorrect but their label order will be correct. So instead of looking line is it possible to check label? For example, between creation and execution. Time diff= Line[Creation] - Line[execution]

Comment: @nobody Which thing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220699/discussion-between-r0ot293-and-nobody).